# how to send email notification when recurring donation is due

Tags: npsp

I run a not for profit and beginner to NPSP. I am unable to find out how to generate an email for recurring donation when the donation amount is due. For example, I create a recurring donation ($1000) for a contact with monthly instalment. I want to generate email notification (with a .CSV file of opportunity data) to my accountant to invoice the donor. Accountant's system can accept only .CSV file to generate invoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce cannot natively generate CSV files. The closest approximation to this requirement is probably going to be a [Scheduled Report Run](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_schedule.htm&type=5).

You'd need to design a report that includes only those Recurring Donations that are ready to be paid, and schedule the report either for a user whose email address routes to your accountant, or to a user with an appropriate email system filter set up to forward the message accordingly.

The result will, however, not be a CSV file; it will be an Salesforce report export, which is an HTML table that can be read as a spreadsheet by Microsoft Excel.

If you need a genuine CSV file and the process must be automated in this way, there will be more work you'll need to do - either using local automation to run the Salesforce Data Loader and script an email send, integrating another cloud-based automation product, or doing custom development in Salesforce. In any of those cases you'll probably want to engage a local consultant if you don't have the technical resources in-house.